# How can I create and calculate distance table using location table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlgeography

I have a TruckLocation table in SQL.

```
Select top 4 *
from TruckLocation
order by ReadTime desc
```

Result:

```
OID      TruckID    Lat     Lng          Speed            ReadTime
123       33      37.4060    37.1470         58           2013-11-26 00:39:00.000
334       23      40.735     35.8159         90           2013-11-26 00:33:00.000
123       33      37.4060    37.1470         58           2013-11-26 00:31:00.000
334       23      42.735     36.3159         85           2013-11-26 00:27:00.000
```

I want to create a new table or store procedure result is to  like this :

```
  Time           TruckID      TotalDistance(KM) 
  2013-11-26     23           125,1245484
  2013-11-25     23           123,1245484
  2013-11-24     23           43,1245484
  2013-11-23     23           434,1245484
  2013-11-22     23           56,1245484
  2013-11-21     23           85,1245484
  .              .             .
  .              .             .
  .              18            1215,4544
  .              .             .
```

I tried but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't created a table structure to verify this but something like the following might be of use:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(40.735 35.8159)', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(42.735 36.3159)', 4326);
--SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(readtime AS VARCHAR(11)),103), truckid, @g.STDistance(@h)
FROM [trucklocation]
GROUP BY readtime
```

This uses SQL Server 2008's inbuilt georgraphy support.

You can read about STGeomFromText here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933834(v=sql.100).aspx
And you can read about STDistance here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808(v=sql.100).aspx